# typo3/cms install with composer issue

Tags: php, content-management-system, composer-php, installation, typo3

I am really new in learning about CMS. 
I started to create a test projekt for learning about TYPO3 and creating extbase ext.

Now I am stucked in installing TYPO3 with composer, it shows me this Problem.

couldnt find something in the web about this problem.

What do I have to do next? What do i have to looking for in the internet to solve the problem, or could one of you explain me  (if quick), whats wrong here?[**my terminal Problem**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTI13.png)

Comment: You are missing a PHP extension, specifically the `xml` extension. Just install it - on Ubuntu and Debian you can do that using `sudo apt-get install php5-xml` or `sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml`, depending on your Ubuntu/Debian version.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the PHP extension **xml** which is one requirement to use TYPO3. Make sure you have enabled it in your server configuration. How this works depends on your environment thus you should check its documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

The composer error message tells you pretty clear what the problem is and what you have to do:

The Problem: PHP extension ext-xml is not installed

The Solution: Install it and activate it in the CLI context

Comment: You may add to your answer that it is a difference to have the php-xml extension installed and activated for your webserver like PHP-apache or PHP-fpm or for the PHP-cli